# CMake: include libraries in the project

Tags: c, cmake

I'm new to CMake and I need help.
I'm trying to develop the following `cmaketutorial` project:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── lib1
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── lib1.h
│   └── lib2
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── lib2.c
│       └── lib2.h
└── cmaketutorial
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── cmaketutorial.c
```

`lib1`: general purpose library. It only contains a .h and its CMakeFiles.txt allows you to install it in `/usr/local/include`.

`lib2`: general purpose library. It contains a .c and .h and its CMakeFiles.txt allows you to install it in `/usr/local/include`.

`lib1 and lib2`: they are two libraries that exist by themselves and are taken from their respective projects.

`cmaketutorial`: this is the project in question, it contains a `.c` that includes `lib1` and `lib2`.

`CMakeLists.txt (root)`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(
    cmaketutorial
    VERSION 0.0.1
    LANGUAGES C
)

add_definitions(-D_GNU_SOURCE)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter")

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(cmaketutorial)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` (`root/lib`)

```
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` (`root/lib/lib1`)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(
    lib1
    VERSION 0.0.1
    LANGUAGES C
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(
    lib1
    INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

# install rules
install(FILES lib1.h DESTINATION include)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` (`root/lib/lib2`)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(
    lib2
    VERSION 0.0.1
    LANGUAGES C
)

if(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
    set(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)

add_library(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    lib2.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib2.h
)

target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES lib2.h DESTINATION include)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` (`root/cmaketutorial`)

```
# add the executable
add_executable(cmaketutorial cmaketutorial.c)

target_include_directories(
    cmaketutorial PUBLIC
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

With current `CMakeFiles *` when compiling `cmaketutorial.c` it cannot link `lib1` and `lib2`.
How can I modify the general `CMakeFiles.txt` so that everything goes as it should?
Can I use the original `CMakeFiles.txt` of `lib1` and `lib2`?

Also, could I set up the project for which includes in `cmaketutorial.c` have the form `#include <lib/lib1.h>` and `#include <lib/lib2.h>`?

Comment: Show `cmaketutorial/CMakeLists.txt`. Did you link with `lib1` and `lib2`? `PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` - what does this do?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated with cmaketutorial cmakefiles.txt

Comment: So you don't link `cmaketutorial` executable with `lib1` nor with `lib2`, so it doesn't know about them. I guess add `target_link_libraries(cmaketutorial PUBLIC lib1 lib2)`. To use the form `lib/lib1.h` you need to move `lib1.h` inside a directory named `lib`. So move `lib1.h` to `root/lib/lib1/lib/lib1.h`. Or use `#include <lib1.h>`. If you want to just build the project, I think you could just remove all the `install()` calls. And why `set(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`? What is going on with `BINARY_DIR SOURCE_DIR` in lib2?

Comment: Also adding `target_link_libraries (cmaketutorial PUBLIC lib1 lib2)` does not work.

Comment: `does not work` is a bit vague. Did anything change? Did you reconfigure cmake after the change? How are you building the project? Another couple of side notes: In "modern cmake" instead of `add_definitions(-D_GNU_SOURCE)` do `set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS TRUE)` and instead of `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS` use `add_compile_options()`

Comment: I recreated all the files and only added `target_link_libraries (cmaketutorial PUBLIC lib1 lib2)` to `cmaketutorial/CMakeLists.txt` and typed `cmake` and `make` and it successfully builded and linked with both libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I modify the general CMakeFiles.txt so that everything goes as it should?

You have to link `cmaketutorial` executable with `lib1` and `lib2` libraries. Add `target_link_libraries (cmaketutorial PUBLIC lib1 lib2)` to `cmaketutorial/CMakeLists.txt`.

> could I set up the project for which includes in cmaketutorial.c have the form #include  and #include ?

Move those files into appriopriate directories. So do:

```
mkdir lib/lib1/lib lib/lib2/lib
mv lib/lib1/lib1.h lib/lib1/lib
mv lib/lib2/lib2.h lib/lib2/lib/lib2.h
```

and then update `lib/lib2/CMakeLists.txt` with `add_library(... lib/lib2.h)` and update all the `install` rules when needed.

Comment: Thank you. I examine my project and found a syntax error. With `target_link_libraries ...` now it works.